# Apache HTTPS site visible locally but not from remote

Tags: iptables, remote-access, apache2, ufw

I am bringing up a new HTTPS server that I hope to make available publicly. This is on Ubuntu 16.04.

I'm having difficulty in that the site cannot be seen remotely.  I have properly configured the router that allows access to the appropriate server, and in fact the server UFW logs seem to show that the requests do come in, but are blocked:

```
Mar  5 07:07:18 oc9 kernel: [35729.338614] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens32 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:53:67:c0:2c:56:dc:54:96:a8:08:00 SRC=192.168.158.175 DST=192.168.158.64 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=52285 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47801 DPT=515 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Mar  5 07:08:01 oc9 kernel: [35772.752517] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens32 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:44:52:ec:8c:2d:08:00 SRC=192.168.158.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2
Mar  5 07:08:56 oc9 kernel: [35827.268215] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens33 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:40:b7:f3:dd:a5:40:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2
Mar  5 07:10:06 oc9 kernel: [35897.823432] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens32 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:94:44:52:ec:8c:2d:08:00 SRC=192.168.158.254 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2
```

I am using UFW and its status is:

```
ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80,443/tcp (Apache Full)   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80,443/tcp (Apache Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Last thing I know of to include here is the output from iptables -vL, but I don't know what I'm looking at here.

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 835 packets, 34384 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
57949 3365K ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
57949 3365K ufw-before-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
53255 2900K ufw-after-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
  835 34384 ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
  835 34384 ufw-reject-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
  835 34384 ufw-track-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ufw-before-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ufw-after-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ufw-reject-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ufw-track-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 3514  644K ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
 3514  644K ufw-before-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
   75  5592 ufw-after-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
   75  5592 ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
   75  5592 ufw-reject-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
   75  5592 ufw-track-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  772 60972 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
  879  215K ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
  203 12180 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
   19  7798 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
50547 2570K ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  835 34384 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
    0     0 ufw-user-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  160 11840 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere
 4481  448K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    1    40 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
    1    40 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
    3   252 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
    4  1312 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc
53300 2903K ufw-not-local  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
53300 2903K ufw-user-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  160 11840 ACCEPT     all  --  any    lo      anywhere             anywhere
 3279  627K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   75  5592 ufw-user-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    1    40 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
    0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  587 36448 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
  564 18056 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
52149 2848K RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
    0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
52420 2866K DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   16   960 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
   59  4632 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   43  2532 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https /* 'dapp_Apache%20Full' */
    2   104 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh /* 'dapp_OpenSSH' */

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

This is the output from "ss -ltnp" :

`State      Recv-Q Send-Q                                                                Local Address:Port                                                                               Peer Address:Port
LISTEN     0      128                                                                       127.0.0.1:3306                                                                                          :                   users:(("mysqld",pid=1594,fd=16))
LISTEN     0      128                                                                               *:22                                                                                            :                   users:(("sshd",pid=1285,fd=3))
LISTEN     0      128                                                                              :::80                                                                                           :::*                   users:(("apache2",pid=1947,fd=4),("apache2",pid=1944,fd=4),("apache2",pid=1943,fd=4),("apache2",pid=1942,fd=4),("apache2",pid=1941,fd=4),("apache2",pid=1940,fd=4),("apache2",pid=1937,fd=4))
LISTEN     0      128                                                                              :::22                                                                                           :::*                   users:(("sshd",pid=1285,fd=4))
LISTEN     0      128                                                                              :::443                                                                                          :::*                   users:(("apache2",pid=1947,fd=6),("apache2",pid=1944,fd=6),("apache2",pid=1943,fd=6),("apache2",pid=1942,fd=6),("apache2",pid=1941,fd=6),("apache2",pid=1940,fd=6),("apache2",pid=1937,fd=6))`

This is the output from "openssl s_client -connect 192.168.158.158:443:

`openssl s_client -connect 192.168.158.158:443
    CONNECTED(00000003)
    depth=0 C = US, ST = State, L = City, O = LuvSoft, CN = site.domain.com, emailAddress = ssl-admin@domain.com
    verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
    verify return:1
    depth=0 C = US, ST = State, L = City, O = LuvSoft, CN = site.domain.com, emailAddress = ssl-admin@domain.com
    verify return:1
    ---
    Certificate chain
     0 s:/C=US/ST=State/L=City/O=LuvSoft/CN=site.domain.com/emailAddress=ssl-admin@domain.com
       i:/C=US/ST=State/L=City/O=LuvSoft/CN=site.domain.com/emailAddress=ssl-admin@domain.com
    ---
    Server certificate
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    MIID6TCCAtGgAwIBAgIJANpH0YKSCE+FMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGKMQswCQYD
        et cetera
    q3jJ5FRjd6cWaPKJ25UeMdKJCbpCnmlLadMy3oSDTfqk3UTymhUiJhIgm9S2
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    subject=/C=US/ST=State/L=City/O=LuvSoft/CN=site.domain.com/emailAddress=ssl-admin@domain.com
    issuer=/C=US/ST=State/L=City/O=LuvSoft/CN=site.domain.com/emailAddress=ssl-admin@domain.com
    ---
    No client certificate CA names sent
    Peer signing digest: SHA512
    Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
    ---
    SSL handshake has read 1517 bytes and written 431 bytes
    ---
    New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Server public key is 2048 bit
    Secure Renegotiation IS supported
    Compression: NONE
    Expansion: NONE
    No ALPN negotiated
    SSL-Session:
        Protocol  : TLSv1.2
        Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
        Session-ID: AAC21087FEAB3ED0D391F3C5AF78FCCF717AE456D107591B7B9FDADD03E44D4C
        Session-ID-ctx:
        Master-Key: 9FA0F50D914170495DCEDFE73AEA1AFDC86491C814F582794C4D55C2265EDC1415A57ADC282992ADF5DC6AF4161F6D19
        Key-Arg   : None
        PSK identity: None
        PSK identity hint: None
        SRP username: None
        Start Time: 1488762616
        Timeout   : 300 (sec)
        Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
    ---`

What might I check to see where this has gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

At you iptables output, what you're looking for is in the chain ufw-user-input

The first line enables ports 80 and 443, where it sais `multiport dports http,https`

I think you're misreading the ufw logs. where you see `DST=224.0.0.1` it means your firewall blocks multicast, and at the first line you can see `DPT=515` which means destination port is 515 and not 443.

To make sure the firewall doesn't block you, you can try running on the remote host `telnet $HTTP_SERVER 443`. If you are being blocked you should immediately get connection refused, because your basic policy is `deny`

Comment: I would avoid telnet for testing HTTPS, and maybe use `openssl s_client` instead. That said - the firewall output shows accepts for the HTTP/S rule, so I would either ask for a bit more information about how the issue presents. `tcpdump` might also help shed some light on all this, as would some output from `ss -ltnp` (or `netstat -plnt` if `ss` isn't around)

Comment: Not at a computer now.  How the issue presents itself: Apache website appears on the same network, but times out remotely.  If I point the firewall to a different server, I can see locally and remotely.  Probably right that I'm misreading the log, but local tests don't help much since it does work locally.  However, if I could get a log of allowed and disallowed connections, that'd be very helpful.  Any ideas there?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that, with a change AT&T made to their firmware, the NVG589 router will not direct NAT/Gaming traffic to a NEW DHCP-derived address.  If you had a dynamic address specified at the time of the firmware upgrade, it seems that's OK, but any new ones will not be honored for port passthru.  There is no error message, no warning, no indication at all of why it won't work or of whether its working - and no way either to see what the firewall's doing.

At any rate, this was resolved by specifying a fixed IP address (on the router) for the server, and then reconfiguring the HTTPS protocol.